# Need to use the string from other class

Tags: java

I am trying to access a String in one class from another. The first class is shown below:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class UseData {
Connection connection=null;

public void usePart1Part2(String part1, String part2, String part3, String part4) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String date = format.format(new Date());

    connection = SQliteConnectionClass.dbconnector();
    try {

        String value1 = part1;   //
        String value2 = part2;   //
        String value3 = part3;   //
        String value4 = part4;   // data need to be used in GenerateSummonPDF.java
        String Timestamp = date;
```

value1 to value4 are used in the GenerateSummonPDF class below:

```
public class GenerateSummonPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\enforement system\\Summon PDF list\\Serial No.pdf"));
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("the data(value1 to value4 need to print it out here"));  //here is where i need the data
            document.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: shall i wirte a sample code or u want a modification in exactly this code

Comment: Either use a setter, or pass it as a parameter to a method. You seem to be coding pretty advanced material for someone who doesn't know how to pass a String (or any other) object from one class to another.

Comment: modification if possible to make it straight, so that i can understand clearer.thaks @KumarSaurabh

Comment: What's your specific problem? Are you unsure how to use an instance of ``usedata `` (which should be capitalized following the Java standards) in your ``GenerateSummonPDF``'s main method?

Comment: @Keith because the data i get is from serial port. Im not so sure and this code im just trying out. thanks

Comment: @calvinern where are you calling ``usePart1Part2(String part1...)``? Try commenting your code to understand each line's intent and order of execution. Or even do a quick sequence diagram. I don't believe your current design is going to serve you.

Comment: @Keith the usePart1Part2(string part1...) is the string data obtain from other class ( from serial port which in this case i uses txrx)

Comment: Also learn on naming conventions of java

Comment: Please refer the java basics.

Comment: @calvin ern kindly accept the answer which was most helpful, if any.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a getter. Here is a demonstration of a getter added as a method to UseData:

```
        public class UseData {

        private String value1;

        public void usePart1Part2(String part1, String part2, String part3, String part4)
        {
            value1 = part1;
        }

        /**
         * Getter for value1
         * @return the value1
         */
        public String getValue1() {
            return value1;
        }

    }
```

As for calling the getter from the other class:

```
    public class GenerateSummonPDF {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            UseData usedata = new UseData();
            String value1 = usedata.getValue1();
        }

    }
```

Comment: then i should call the getValue1 in the next class?

Comment: Yupp call these method in your next class

Comment: @calvin ern to answer your question I added a demonstration of calling the getter.

Comment: @OferYuval i have tried the way you showed above, and i found out that is not really what i wanted. For The string data in "usePart1Part2" are keep on updating. And the above code is keep on returning the value which is something like "part1Value"

Comment: @calvin ern you may need a solution like an observable object, but i think it is a different question. I suggest that you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post another question describing your need.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class usedata { 
   Connection connection=null;
   String value1;   //
   String value2;   //
   String value3;   //
   String value4;  
public void usePart1Part2(String part1, String part2, String part3, String part4)
{
    Date curDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String DateToStr = format.format(curDate);

    connection= SQliteConnectionClass.dbconnector();
try {

   value1 = part1;   //
   value2 = part2;   //
   value3 = part3;   //
   value4 = part4;   // data need to be used in GenerateSummonPDF.java
   String Timestramp = DateToStr;
}

public String getValue1()
{
   return value1;    
} 

public String getValue2()
{
  return value2;    
} 

public String getValue3()
{
  return value3;    
} 

public String getValue4()
{
  return value4;    
}
```

then in your next class make object and get value from these methods
Some thing like this

```
useData obj=new UseData();
String s=obj.getValue1();
```

I hope you get from this. 
Happy learning java

Comment: I edited to  fix I identaion to make it more readable, and up-voted.

Comment: thanks for the edit. One edit i wanted to do myself was that the class name is also not good but here the asker seems to be new to java so didnt complicated things. 

Stack is all about improvement so thanks for taking time out for edit

Comment: @KumarSaurabh i have tried the way you showed above, and i found out that is not really what i wanted. For The string data in "usePart1Part2" are keep on updating. And the above code is keep on returning the value which is something like "part1Value"

Comment: what do u mean by usePart1Part2. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class UseData {
    private String value1 ;
    private String value2 ;
    private  String value3 ;

// getter- setter for value1 , value2 , value3
// rest of the code.

}

now add modify GenerateSummonPDF as follows :

    public class GenerateSummonPDF {

public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Document document = new Document();
      try
      {


 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\enforement system\\Summon PDF list\\Serial No.pdf"));
         document.open();

          UseData useData = new UseData ();
          useData.usePart1Part2("part1Value" , "part2Value" ,"part3Value" ,"part4Value") ;        

         document.add(new Paragraph("the data("+useData.getValue1()+useData.getValue2()+useData.getValue3()+useData.getValue4()+"));  //here is where i need the data


         document.close();
         writer.close();
      } catch (DocumentException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class usedata {
public String part1;
public String part2;
public String part3;
public String part4;
Connection connection=null;

public void usePart1Part2(String part1, String part2, String part3, String part4)
{
this.part1 = part1
this.part2 = part2
this.part3 = part3
this.part4 = part4
Date curDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
connection= SQliteConnectionClass.dbconnector();
try {

   String value1 = part1;   //
   String value2 = part2;   //
   String value3 = part3;   //
   String value4 = part4;   // data need to be used in 
   String Timestramp = DateToStr;
....

public class GenerateSummonPDF {

public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      userdata ud = new userdata();
      //you can't acces to the other class attribut
      System.out.println(ud.part1 + ud.part2 + ud.part3 + ud.part4);
      Document document = new Document();
      try
      {
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\enforement system\\Summon PDF list\\Serial No.pdf"));
     document.open();
     document.add(new Paragraph("the data(value1 to value4 need to print it out here"));  //here is where i need the data
     document.close();
     writer.close();
      } catch (DocumentException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
   }
```